# Connection between Android Server and Laptop Client using same wifi

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

I want to connect android server application with laptop client java which connected on same wifi network.

i try the following code.

laptop client code

```
 String IPToConnect="192.168.0.";
    int i=0;

    Socket skt;
    PrintWriter pw;
    try
    {
        for(i=105;i<=199;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                skt=new Socket(IPToConnect+i,4444);
                pw=new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(),true);
                pw.write("KP");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                skt.close();    
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               continue;
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and android server code

```
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket client;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader br;
private static String message;
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444)

 try
        {
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            message = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(""+message);
            inputStreamReader.close();
            client.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("HELLO ERROR");
        }
```

above code working fine for me

i want the program working like this

1. Android mobile app and laptop connected through same wifi network
2. when android app start it display the laptop on list when laptop start that client application

above code working fine but it may be not work when different router use different ip addresses means not start with(192.168.0) and it send request to all device means it time consuming

so please help me to solve the problem, in short i want to list laptop on android app when laptop start it client app

thank you

Comment: The approach you are using will have alot of problems. There are alot third party libs that will help you achive this functionality. You can try this http://multiscreen.samsung.com/
Ive used it for communication betwen tablet and smart tv, and it works great.

Comment: @BorisPawlowski you can give me any example of that to connect android  mobile app and laptop

Comment: You cannot connect them the way that you think of. You can create server on your laptop and your application to communicate with it. The other way, that Im recommending, is with this libs. You can create two clients:
one android app, and one web client and to communicate with the tools that library gives you. 

I guess there are alot of approaches solving this problem and you can find your answers after some deeper search.

Comment: i want to communicate between laptop and android connected on same wifi connection, and so how i list on android app that which laptop running my app and i try that libs which you give me it not working even demo are there is also not working.. thank you @BorisPawlowski

Comment: `it may be not work when different router use different ip addresses means not start with(192.168.0) `. Indeed. But you should first determine the local ip of the server. And then change that to other addresses in the pool. Start with clientip = serverip +1 or serverip -1. And so on.